# ruby cast method input variable as string in ruby irb

Tags: ruby, irb

How would I coerce the behavior of irb to treat variable identifiers as strings when used in method signatures?

I am trying to create a irb based calculation tool and I want to reduce the typing of users who use this tool in the irb shell. Assume my users are not ruby programmers or know much about the syntax of ruby. The may have some facility with the command line.

I have a file

```
calculator.rb
```

inside this file is

```
def calculate(value, units)

... some logic

end
```

I instruct the user to fire up irb like so

```
irb -r path/to/calculator.rb
```

I instruct the user to type

```
calculate(10, inches)
```

get return value in irb

how can I do this without requiring the user to understand that they have to wrap the second parameter in quotation marks. In other words I don't want the user to have to type

```
calculate(10, "inches")
```

is it possible to cast the user input as a string instead of a variable identifier before it is passed to my method inside my script? Maybe what I want to do is not possible without fundamentally breaking irb shell?

Comment: You'd break more than IRB, because you'd have to recompile Ruby itself. The expectation that strings are delimited is defined in the interpreter itself and is all through everything in the language and scripts used by it. If you did that everything would grind to a halt.

Comment: Recompiling isn't necessary, you could use method_missing instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is for non-programmers how about using `puts` and `gets`?

```
def calculate
  puts "Which number would you like to convert?"
  number = gets.to_i
  puts "What do you want to convert it to?"
  type = gets
  # your conversion logic
  puts result
end
```

Comment: ah yes, that makes much more sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do it the way you requested using method_missing.    Any matching units will get converted to strings instead of raising exceptions.

```
SO_CALC_UNITS = %w[inches feet yards meters parsecs]
def method_missing(method)
  if SO_CALC_UNITS.include?(method.to_s)
    method.to_s
  else
    super(method)
  end
end
```